# How to extract user-data from a custom material in a .mb with the Maya C++ API?

Tags: c++, import, export, maya

How can I extract the data the user entered into my custom material's fields when I'm parsing an .mb with the C++ Maya API in my importing app?  (I suspect I already have access to an MObject that contains the user's input, but don't know how to extract it)

Here's the situation in greater detail:

- I defined a custom material with the C++ Maya API (I created an .mll that defines a custom MPxNode, which in turn defines some float and enum fields for the user)
- in Maya I can "assign new material" to an object with the custom material, and then modify the custom material's datafields and save the .mb
- in my C++ Maya importer I traverse the DAG and DG and, as expected, note one occurrence of the custom material (so noted by identifying the material MObject as the only one for which the call MObject::hasFn(MFn::kPluginDependNode) returns true)
- I can extract each of my custom shader's datafields by name using MFnDependencyNode::attribute("datafieldName") -- trying to extract a nonexistent datafield fails as expected

...but these extracted datafields are MObject's, and I don't know how to extract the data the user entered into the custom material instance in Maya.

What's the right approach here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the missing link I was looking for:

MFnDependencyNode::findPlug("datafieldName") returns an MPlug, which then provides access to the user-entered data.

(I was searching for names like "attribute" and "datafield" -- it didn't occur to me to look for anything called a "plug")

Comment: Plug is sort of a half of an attribute. This why it has its own terminology. The user never gets exposed to this sits just available in the api.

Comment: @joojaa Can you elaborate on what you mean by calling a plug "half an attribute"?  I'm currently thinking of an attribute as a datafield, like a member of a struct in C.  What then, is "half an attribute?"

Comment: An attribute is a instruction for computation, storage is a optional function. When you make a connection the plug primes the attribute to trigger on reading on the other end of the connection. Now the plug on the other side may or may not be a fully qualified storage of a value. It may be that Maya actually only uses the connected data field once from the source plug. The destination may be just an illusion of a storage, unless the attribute is set to cache.

Comment: @joojaa So connecting a plug to an attribute causes that attribute to read from that plug -- and the plug could be a stored datafield, or a one-time computed-value (or maybe a value that's recomputed every time it's queried?)  Does that sound right?

Comment: Yes. Most likely a value that's cached and computed if it needs to be changed. Don't read the data field always ask Maya to compute. This will make Maya decide the computationally best action.